# Why does the error code not have severity and facility code fields?

Tags: c++, winapi

From the [Windows via C/C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735663777) book:

[image]

Ok, I try to get any system error code by Microsoft and to analize its fields:

```
HANDLE hMutex = OpenMutex(0, FALSE, _T("12345")); // some unexisting object 
if (NULL == hMutex) {
    DWORD errCode = GetLastError(); // I get 0x00000002 here
    PTSTR msg = NULL;
    LCID langId = MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL);
    DWORD result = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, errCode, langId, (PTSTR)&msg, 0, NULL);
    wcerr << msg << endl;
    return 2;
}
```

My `errCode` value is `0x00000002`, but I expected it will have the *severinity field* as 3 (error) and some value of the *facility code* field...

Why the gotten result has not the values in these fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoted text describes `NTSTATUS` error codes. These are kernel level error codes. Some documentation can be found here: [Defining New NTSTATUS Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543026.aspx).

However, `GetLastError` returns Win32 error codes. These are, quite simply, different beasts from `NTSTATUS` codes. They do not have severity or facility codes.

MSDN says [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh553585.aspx) about Win32 error codes:

> Win32 error codes are 16-bit values extended to 32-bits with zero fill, and they can be returned by methods or in structures. In general, they are not vendor-extendable.

Your error code is [`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx#ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) which clearly does not fit into the table in your answer because it has a severity of `0` meaning success.

Comment: But author the book is Jeffrey Richter, and this chapter (#1) is about the Win32 error codes...

Comment: @AndreyBushman: The book is misleading you.  What David said is correct.  Severities and Facilities only apply to COM `HRESULT` error codes, not to Win32 error codes. And `GetLastError()` only applies when a Win32 API function fails, unless documented otherwise. In the case of `OpenMutex()`, `GetLastError()` is only meaningful if `OpenMutex()` returns a NULL mutex handle, which your code is not checking for.

Comment: Actually, on second glance, that table is something similar to a COM error code, but not the same thing. But it's not a Win32 error code either.

Comment: I fixed my code: the `if (NULL == hMutex)` instead of the `if (S_OK != errCode)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: what the table describes is actually lower-level NT error codes, which are similar to COM `HRESULT` error codes with a slightly different layout for the Severity and Facility fields.

Comment: I saw the comment about the `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32` macro (about the mapping a `system error code` to the `HRESULT` value), but it disappeared now... It was usefull too.

Comment: @AndreyBushman: I deleted the comment, since the book talks about `NTSTATUS` codes, not COM `HRESULT`s. `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32` applies to the latter only. It is not related to the question or this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you go about 26,000 lines into winerror.h you will find the layout of the error code fields. It is different than the above table 1-2. EX: Facility is bits 26-16 and bit 26 separates Microsoft from other codes, 1024 facility codes each.

Near the layout are the definitions of SUCCEEDED(hr) and FAILED(hr). But more interestingly, just below them are definitions related to error codes sets.

```
HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(unsigned long x)
HRESULT_FROM_NT(x)
```

For example, CreateFile() might return the 16 bit error code.

```
#define ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED              5L
```

and you use HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(x) to turn it into the HRESULT

```
#define E_ACCESSDENIED                   _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80070005L)
```

Meanwhile, _open() might return its own 16 bit error code from the  XENIX compatible error codes defined in errno.h.

```
#define EACCES          13
```

The basic issue/problem is that there are multiple error code sets. You can't just use HRESULT_FROM_WIN32 with every error returned. The sets overlap numerically and you need to know the API call that sourced the failure to know which error code map to use.

Finally, though COM errors are 32 bit Windows error codes, this error code format/layout did not originate with COM. They preceded COM. I would simply call them HRESULTS.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.